# Change the hyperlink style in glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I'm using `hyperref` with `glossaries`. Per default, glossaries use `\hyperlink{<target>}{<text>}` to generate the hyperlink. This results in the default link color being used (typically, red, or whatever is defined by `linkcolor` or `linkbordercolor`). I would like the color of the glossaries links to be different than the standard link color, say, blue instead of red.

I read the [extended manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glsdisplay) of `glossaries` but couldn't figure it out.

The closest I got was this:

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={0 0 1}}#1\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={1 0 0}}}
```

but `glstextformat` changes the text inside the hyperlink, such that I miss the moment where the hyperlink is created, so it's too late to change the color. So what happens with my command is, after the hyperlink is created, I quickly change the color of all the next links to blue and then immediately change it back, which makes no difference, of course.

I also tried `glossaries-extra`:

```
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{hyperoutside}{false}
\newcommand{\myformat}[2]{234 #1 #2 123 123}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{textformat}{myformat}
```

in the hope that the second argument to the `textformat` command will be the link to use in the hyperlink, but there was no second argument.

Thanks!

EDIT: here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{entry}{
    name=glossary entry,
    description={Test description}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{test}{TEST}{This Entry Stands for Test} 

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{tag}{Something something}

Want this \gls{entry} to be blue.

This is a simple hyperlink, which should be the default red \hyperlink{tag}{some link}.

Want this next glossary link to be blue again: \gls{test}.

Thanks.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should provide a small but complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: I don't think an example would help but I added one nevertheless. This question requires in-depth glossaries knowledge, I assume the people who have the knowledge would not need an example.

Comment: well you can naturally wait until the one with in-depth glossaries knowledge comes along and answers your question without needing an example, but until then people with the knowledge how to use `\tracingmacros` on an existing example can be useful too.  You can try `\pretocmd\glsxtrprotectlinks{\color{blue}}{}{\fail}`, but imho glossaries has no easy hook for this and it doesn't use the hyperref commands in a way that would allow hyperref to do something. You should make a feature request for a real solution.

Comment: > *imho glossaries has no easy hook for this*  
Yeah, you're probably right. I would expect such a customization to have a proper hook but I really can't find it in the manual. I'll wait a bit more and if nothing happens I'll try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: you can also try `\pretocmd\gls{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue}}{}{\fail}
\newcommand*{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=red}}`. But nothing feels really right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly, but it works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\let\oldgls=\gls
\renewcommand{\gls}[1]{{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue}%
  \oldgls{#1}}}%

\makeglossaries

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{entry}{
    name=glossary entry,
    description={Test description}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{test}{TEST}{This Entry Stands for Test} 

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{tag}{Something something}

Want this \gls{entry} to be blue.

This is a simple hyperlink, which should be the default red \hyperlink{tag}{some link}.


Want this next glossary link to be blue again: \gls{test}.

Thanks.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, I tried to do this with `\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={0 0 1}}#1\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={1 0 0}}}` but it didn't help.

Comment: Your new solution is something that I had in mind as a last resort. There are a bunch of gls commands like `\glspl`, `\Gls` etc, so I'd have to redefine them all, but they're not too many. I was thinking of defining my own commands, but I like your solution with `renewcommand` more, thanks.

Comment: BTW, it turns out that the color can be set locally.

Comment: could you come up with a macro to call this for all the gls commands? In case you're good with Tex macros. The commands are `\gls`, `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`, `\glsdisp`. So basically something like `\def\redefinegls#1{\let\old#1=\#1 \renewcommand{\#1}[1] {{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=gls_links}\old#1{#1}}}}   FOREACHINTHELIST \redefinegls{ELEMENT}` I'm really bad with Tex macros as you can see.

Comment: I would use \csname #1\endcsname and remove the backslashes, e.g `\foreach \name in {gls,Gls,GLS, etc.} {\expandafter\let\csname old\name\endcsname=\csname \name\endcsname etc.}`  Actually, I wouldn't bother with a loop, just copy and edit over and over.